# Yii 2 starter kit - docker In file .\.env: environment variable name 'YII_DEBUG ' may not contains whitespace. event returned with error code 1

Tags: docker, docker-compose, yii2

When building site via Yii 2 starter kit on docker on windows - issuing command
`composer run-script docker:build`, the build fails with the message

Output:

```
> cp .env.dist .env
> docker-compose up --force-recreate -d
In file .\.env: environment variable name 'YII_DEBUG       ' may not contains whitespace.
Script docker-compose up --force-recreate -d handling the docker:start event returned with error code 1
Script @docker:start was called via docker:build
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default `.env.dist` file in the root directory contains environmental variables formatted/aligned with spaces, and the docker fails to parse them.

Therefore a workaround solution is to replace all the space characters in the environmental variables file `.env.dist` with no character, eg. in Notepad++ editor. Subsequently it works.